# Authentication with WSO2 API Manager

Tags: api, authentication, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a system with three layer includes API Server (Backend), Client Web Site, and End User. Now, the Authentication occurs on API Server, which be done in two case. In one case, Client Web Site call API directly using a token (Client Token) which get from a service based on user/pass and in another case, besides End User login into API Server using Client Web Site, but authentication occurred on API Server other than Client Web Site. Client Site get another token which named as Auth Token (for end user calling), then call API that End User requested  by sending two mentioned tokens. By using Client and Auth Tokens, API Server checks whether client and end User are logged in respectively or not. Entities and their relations are illustrated [in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XaKS.png)

I want to use API Manager as a gateway between API Server and Client Site and manage authentication process with it.
How can I implement this scenario using WSO2 API Manger?
thanks for your response!

Comment: It is slightly difficult to read the post (some formatting and verbosing would help as some parts are not really clear ).  What do you mean by `authentication occurred on API Server other than Client Web Site` ? ` By using Client and Auth Tokens` only a single token is used, however the requested token (using code or password OAuth profile) is bound to the application and to the user (both must be valid). Only subscribed applications would be able to use an API)

Comment: the client web site is a third party application that placed between our API server ans end user and didn't implement the authentication process itself (checking user and pass of end users). in one scenario when a user login to client website, it pass the user & pass to API server. therefore, API server checks the validity of U&P and creates a Auth token as well creates a session for user. after this time, fore each request from end user the API server checks the map of session, that whether Client web site and end user are logged in or not. the checking process performed by two tokens.

Comment: and in another scenario client web site call API directly without any request from end user.in this scenario auth token is not exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending the previous answer..

If the backend is behind the API manager (adviced), the API maanger can pass the client/user/application information to the backend as JWT token. So indeed, that's a good use case to use the API Manager

Edit: extending answer based on comments

> in one scenario when a user login to client website, it pass the user
>   & pass to API server. therefore, API server checks the validity of U&P

Indeed, using the default OAuth (code or password profile) will work.

> and creates a Auth token as well creates a session for user.

Almost good. A token is returned, there's no user session in API Manager. All authorization is based on the token provided.

> of session, that whether Client web site and end user
>   are logged in or not. the checking process performed by two tokens

Nope. The APIM doesn't check for any session. It checks only the OAuth (Bearer) token.

> and in another scenario client web site call API directly without any
>   request from end user.in this scenario auth token is not exist

The web site (lets call it Application) can authenticate using its own credentials (so called client_credentials profile). It may receive its own OAuth application token.

Comment: Thanks, please refer to my answer to Mr Bhathiya which showing my requirement!

Comment: @DavidbIR keep it simple man.  The APIM is working some way and you are assuming some things which may be not true :) see the edit

Comment: it is not my assumption, it is a real system that working now and I have to follow it because of resistance..:) . indeed, I agree to this complication, so I want to simplify it using API Manager!

Comment: based on your response I find that we can not have two authentication tokens on API Manager. So, is it a good manner that I implement only client token for Application authentication and end user authentication remain as implemented now?

Comment: @DavidbIR you can have two tokens (user and application), but send only one based on who the real client is for the particular call - if it is the end-user or the application.

Answer (score 0):

The same feature is supported in APIM. You can simply get rid of authentication login from your backend (or replace with a simple one) and use APIM Authentication.

APIM uses OAuth2. To cater your requirement, you can use different grant types. For client website, you can use client credentials grant type, and for end users, you can use other grant types such as password or authorization code.

For more details read:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Quick+Start+Guide
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Token+API

Comment: Thanks for your responses. But I want to generate and handle the second token (Auth Token) using APIM rather than passing it to API Server and handling on it. Can I do it or is better pass the Auth Token to backend? Also I update my post, please refer to it for more information. thanks!

Comment: @Bhathiya I do aplologize, I edited the wrong answer (your instead of mine), please refuse the edit